# Reduce conic sections to standard form

Tags: geometry, vectors, conic-sections, quadratic-forms

I have some problems in reducing these conic sections to their standard form and i ask for help to solve them.

$x^2-4xy+4y^2+x+y=5$

$x^2-2xy+3y^2+x+y=6$

Also if I don't ask too much, I would like them to be solved this way:

Example:

$x^2+2xy+5y^2+2x+2y+2=0$

$x^2+2xy+5y^2+2x+2y+2=(x+y)^2+4y^2+2(x+y)+1+1=(x+y+1)^2+4y^2+1=X^2+Y^2+1$

With $X=x+y+1$ and $Y=2y$.

Thank you.

Comment: The first is a parabola and a version of the equation that you can read the focus and directrix off of, is $$5\,\left(-\left({{y}\over{\sqrt{5}}}+{{2\,x}\over{\sqrt{5}}}-{{17
 }\over{2\,\sqrt{5}}}\right)^2+\left(y-{{8}\over{5}}\right)^2+\left(x
 -{{33}\over{10}}\right)^2\right)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Start by completing the square for $x^2-4xy$ to get rid of the $-4xy$ term, i.e. 
$$x^2-4xy+4y^2+x+y=5 \iff (x-2y)^2+x+y=5$$
Now let $X=x-2y$ and $Y=3y$ to give $$X^2+X+Y=5.$$
Can you see what the curve is now?

The second one is similar, but this time choose $Y=\sqrt{2}y$ so that $x^2-2xy+3y^2$ becomes $X^2+Y^2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now everything is more clear but there are two things I don't understand.First i am still unable to get from $X^2+X+Y=5$ to the standard form and second where did you put $x+y-6$ in the second exercise to get $X^2+Y^2$ ?thank you again.

Comment: Assuming standard form for a parabola is something like $4p(y-k)=(x-h)^2$, we have $-Y-5=X^2+X$, so now complete the square for $X$ to obtain $-Y-\frac{19}{4}=(X+\frac{1}{2})^2$. Then let $X'=X+\frac{1}{2}$ and $Y'=Y$.

Comment: For the second one, I have just told you how to make a start. You still need to write $x+y-6$ in terms of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thank you.Very helpful.